# Webpack dist build html layout is different than development

Tags: webpack

I have a weird issue with webpack after i finish my work and build the layout is slightly different for h1, to be specific the spacing is different

Dev version 
[image]

when i build i get less spacing between each word
[image]

When i build all files are building successfully no errors and all seems good but the spacing is different

what causing this to be happening is making me go crazy, and my build configuration are really simple here is it anyway,

```
const path = require('path');
const common = require('./webpack.common');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const FaviconsWebpackPlugin = require('favicons-webpack-plugin');



module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    filename: 'app.[contentHash].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin(),
      new TerserPlugin(),
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({filename: '[name].[contentHash].bundle.css'}),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/template.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeAttributeQuotes: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeComments: true,
      },
    }),
    new FaviconsWebpackPlugin({
      logo: './src/media/favicon.png',
      prefix: 'media/fav',
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

dev tools are identical, how ever the result is different !
[image]
[image]

Comment: when you look at the classes in dev tools styles, what are the differences between the two? From where those class are coming from? which .css? you can see it in the top right corner of each class.

Comment: They are exactly same, i updated with some pictures, would be great if you check that

Comment: Their font-family is different, try adding `\`` to `roslindale` in production in dev tools, see if it changes the spacing. Check it in the dev tools first just to see if this is the problem

Comment: No, i did that nothing changes unfortunately

Comment: Any suggestions ?